# Populate select with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to repopulate the select box on select change.

What i did so far (does not work):

```
$('select#mnt').change(function(){

     var month = $(this).val();
     var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
     var toMonth = <?php echo $tomon; ?>;
     var toDay = <?php echo $today; ?>;
     var result='';

     if (month!=toMonth) {

        for(var i=1; i<=days;i++){

            result += '<option>'+i+'</option>';

        }

        $('select#days').empty().html(result);
     }




  });
```

Comment: Where does the script does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `year` variable in that function. Do you create it elsewhere?

Here's a working example, with some changes:  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SbF3k/25/)

```
$('select#mnt').change(function(){

 var month = $(this).val();
 var days = new Date(2012, month, 0).getDate();
 var toMonth = 5;
 var toDay = 4;
 var result='';

 if (month!=toMonth) {

    for(var i=1; i<=days;i++){

        result += '<option>'+i+'</option>';
    }

    $('select#days').empty().html(result);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i totally overlooked the year variable ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `year` var does not exist in your code snippet:

```
var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```

It should be something like this:

```
var year=2011;//or $('input#year').val();
var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```